# Power factor controller selection

Tags: power-supply, analog, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I would like to design a power supply to a micro-controller based system that will need a 12V as Vin and 6A to feed the whole circuit.

- The system is expected to be an alarm small equipment.
- It is expected to work for a whole day.
- It will have a battery charger controller (Icharge=2A) with a battery pack.
- Sensors.
- LCD.
- Two actuators (draw around 3A.)
- The system will be feed from a main line of 230Vrms and 60Hz line frequency.

I have decided to use a CCM flyback converter to step-down the input voltage to 12VDC. I found this topology to be very easy to design, more practical and well used in many AC/DC converters, but when I come to power factor correction, some questions have been raised in my mind:

1. In my case, with a 72W power needed for the system, do I need a PFC to optimize the power consumption, or I can connect the flyback directly to the main line?
2. In case it is better to use a PFC (as I expect,) how do I choose a better solution (topology?)

From what I have read, the most used topology is the critical or borderline conduction mode boost converter.

3. How do you qualify this solution to my requirements? Is it the best one or I should select another solution?
4. What criteria will help me to decide which topology suits my design?
5. Since this solution steps-up the voltage, will it not affect the efficiency of the downstream converter, since it will step it down again to 12V?

Comment: Tip: to learn the markdown syntax for bulleted lists use the List button on the editor toolbar. That will reveal the `- List item` syntax and you can just type it from then on. Markdown help is built into the editor also. Hit the `?` icon and then select `Lists`.

Comment: Have you read [this application note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8123-D.PDF)?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, Yes I have seen it this morning, but it deals more about calculations

Comment: Design is all about calculations for Pin min:max. Use the MC33260 and read until understood

Comment: The EU mandates power supplies over 100W must have PFC. Is this a consideration? Otherwise, are the benefits from using PFC significant enough to warrant using it based on cost etc?

Comment: If you choose a topology with a constant Ton period then the power factor should be acceptable without any additional correction, although you’ll still need input filtering.  Whether that’s practicable with CCM is another matter, I suspect you’ll struggle.

Answer (score 1):

Flybacks need Common Mode line filters to pass EMI specs.

Active PFC don’t use less power, just less reactive power to the point current matches voltage wave so it appears to have high PF .

Power supplies < 100W do not “need” PFC only >= 100W .

Stepping up the voltage reduces the current demand on a buck components.

TI’s designer for PSU’s will assist you with your spec requirements and their solutions for complete designs and simulations. Analog Devices , ADC as well.